# Google Maps SDK for android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting some conflicting answers when I look at the google website regarding the use of google maps in an android App/ project. It begins by saying that its free to use up to $300 worth of credit or 90 days for the free trial. After this you will be notified and have to pay for the services used over this.

https://cloud.google.com/terms/free-trial/?_ga=2.140946930.-1166978351.1660686736

When continuing to read about using google API  in an android project, it states:

```
The Maps SDK for Android uses a pay-as-you-go pricing model. 
Maps SDK for Android requests generate calls to one of three SKUs: SKU: Mobile Native 
Dynamic Maps, SKU: Dynamic Maps, or SKU: Dynamic Street View. 
Along with the overall Google Terms of Use, there are usage limits specific to the Maps SDK for Android. 
Manage your costs and usage with tools available in the Google Cloud Console.
```

To me this states that I have to pay for the use of google maps api for a project. It also states that it cost $7 per 1000 request.

Any experienced users of google maps who can explain how it really is ? Is it free to use google maps within an android project or do I have to pay for it ?

Appreciate feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after deciding to try it out and see for myself this is what I learned.

Google Maps SDK is free to use for anyone wanting to implement google maps into their project. However, the user has to enter their credit card/ billing information in order to use google maps. This is due to 2 reasons:

1. To prevent fraud/fraudulent activity
2. To make sure you only have 1 account/ you are not a bot

As mentioned before, its completely free to start of with. However, the free version does come to an end when 2 conditions are met.

1. You have used more than $300 worth of usage/ over a certain amount of map calls made with google maps in your project.
2. Your Time period/trial has ended - this is roughly 90 days, from the day you signed up to use their google maps services.

Once either or both of these conditions are met, google maps will cease to function. As for my understanding, once this happens you will need to upgrade to a paid version in order to continue to use google maps services. I am not 100% sure but I believe billing is not automatic, meaning you will have to manually upgrade to a paid version.

Hope this helps anyone wanting to use google maps for a project or just interested in learning how to use it! Happy coding!